# What is wrong with the DOM?

Tags: javascript, api, dom, api-design

Watching the Google Tech Talk YouTube vidoe [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook), Crockford makes the statement

> The DOM is one of the worst APIs
>   imagined

I was interested in exploring this further, but all a Google search has turned up for me is the [Yahoo Developer](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/) page which has talks from both Crockford and Resig on the limitations of the DOM, but all links appear to be dead.

I would be interested if anyone could provide links to any current articles on this subject, or if anyone viewed these talks when they were still available if they could provide a summary of the main points.

Comment: Might be a better fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No need to close it. This is a perfectly solid question. Some professionals remark the the DOM is a bad API. Why is this so? What could have been better?

Comment: @Raynos: Should still be on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ I think.

Comment: @fear The DOM is not a bad API. However, it *is* inferior to the APIs provided by JavaScript libraries like jQuery. Also, the DOM API is not fully implemented in the browsers (especially older versions of IE), which makes it harder to write reliable code (and that's why libraries like jQuery became popular in the first place - they provide cross-browser compatibility).

Comment: @SimeVidas that's _very_ opinionated. I think the jQuery API is inferior to the DOM3 API. jQuery gives you cross browser dom compliance which is lovely but the syntactic sugar is not that useful. It abstracts far too much away.

Comment: The problem isn't the DOM. The DOM itself is wonderful. The problem is one of implementation.

Comment: @Raynos jQuery also gives you new features that are not available in the DOM API (for instance `siblings()` and `empty()`) - that's what I meant when I said that the DOM API is inferior.

Answer (score 2):

> The DOM is one of the worst APIs imagined

I have a feeling that what he actually meant is

> The way every browser implements the DOM API differently makes it one of the worst APIs imagined

I personally don't find the DOM3 API that bad. But crockford has a habit of being opinionated.

Comment: "But crockford has a habit of being opinionated." - The Pacific Ocean has a little bit of water in it.

Comment: @nnnnnn You must remember that for most of the things he says he is correct.

Comment: Yeah, I know. And I do agree with a lot of his opinions. But he doesn't always distinguish between facts and opinions.